# How is floating action button placed with respect to screen height and width in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to get the position of floating action button using media query.

Answer (score 0):

Container in floatinACtionButton Widget

screen radio api : MediaQuery

For example

**//left side floatinButton**

```
 floatingActionButton: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add , size: 30,),
        ),
        Expanded(child: Container())
      ],
    ),

  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
);
```

[image]

**// center floatingButton**

```
 floatingActionButton: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Container()),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _incrementCounter,
              tooltip: 'Increment',
              child: Icon(Icons.add , size: 30,),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container())
          ],
        ),

      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you tell me how far it is placed from the top and left of the screen ?